# how to get the unique number inside ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using angular ng-repeat to show the bootstrap tab. I'm having nested tab inside one another. I need unique id to both tab element and its content. Currently i'm using $index to get the unique. But it fails for more tan two tab inside the parent tab.

```
var items = ['hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3'];

<ul>
  <li id="yui{{$index+1}}" ng-repeat="item in items"></li>
</ul>
```

I want the unique id to the item without using $index. is there any other way to do it?

```
 <ul>
      <li id="yui1">hello1</li>
      <li id="yui2">hello2</li>
      <li id="yui3">hello3</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: `$index`is always unique within ngRepeat. Show us your full code.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parents unique index too, so in your case it would be something like

```
<li id="{{ $parent.$index }}_{{ $index + 1 }} ....
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the unique id or to get the unique string you can create the reusable angularJS Filter, which accepts optional parameters like prefix / $index / suffix and then return the unique string. For example -

```
 angular.module('myApp',[ngRoute]).filter('unique',function(){

    return function(input,prefix){
    var uniqueID = '';
    // generate unique string.
    return uniqueID;
    }
});
```

and then from inside your view -

```
<li id="{{$index | unique:'tab_'}}">test1</li>
```

Comment: That will cause infinite $digest loop.